# expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token

Tags: c, syntax

Having a wierd day with C. I get a compile error `expected ‘)’ before ‘;’` token for the line `else if(inputIntWithinRange(r, 1, MAX_MINES_GRID) == FALSE) validated = FALSE;`

If I comment that line out I no longer get the error. As far as I can tell my syntax is fine, does anybody have an inkling as to what is going on here??

Thanks!

```
do
   {
      validated = TRUE;

      getUserInput(input, MAX_MINES_LENGTH + EXTRA_SPACES);
      sscanf(input, "%d", &r);

      if(inputWithinAllowedLength(input) == FALSE) validated = FALSE;
      else if(inputDigitsOnly(input) == FALSE) validated = FALSE;
      else if(inputIntWithinRange(r, 1, MAX_MINES_GRID) == FALSE) validated = FALSE;
   }
   while(validated == FALSE);
```

Comment: Easiest way to debug that would be to wrap your if and else code blocks in curly braces { } and put it on a new line. You could also simplify the logic there to a single `if(inputWithinAllowedLength(input) == FALSE || inputDigitsOnly(input) == FALSE || inputIntWithinRange(r, 1, MAX_MINES_GRID) == FALSE) validated = FALSE;` and even change the `== FALSE` to a prepended `!` instead.

Comment: what is `MAX_MINES_GRID` defined as?

Comment: I'd be looking at your `#define`s. How is `MAX_MINES_GRID` defined and is the define for `FALSE` ok?

Comment: Success! #define MAX_MINES_GRID 100 had a semi colon at the end. Have removed and now the error is gone. Cheers for the lead...

Comment: Cheers @darvids0n, I reformatted the code for this question, but the actual code is the same as you just mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

I know i'm not answering the question, but I would change code to be:

```
validated = inputWithinAllowedLength(input) 
    && inputDigitsOnly(input)
    && inputIntWithRange(r, 1, MAX_MINDES_GRID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Richard, I like that!